# Wordpress install directory, how to change it?

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, blog

I have my wordpress installation on mywebsite.com/blog

I now want to turn my entire mywebsite.com site into a CMS by use of the Wordpress CMS, whilst still maintaining /blog as the blog area.

Rather than exporting my blog posts, then creating a new WP installation on the top-level directory mywebsite.com and then importing my blog posts.. is there an easier way to do this with use of the existing WP installation?

If it's easier to transfer the files via FTP from /blog/ into the top-level and then adjust the wordpress URL settings that's be amazing! I just don't know how to go about the URL settings side of things..

Thanks!

Comment: This is better suited for webmasters.stackexchange

Answer (score 2):

Read this http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Follow the pre-existing subdirectory instructions.

Answer (score 1):

The process itself isn't that hard.  In your WordPress General settings you will have to change site address to the new directory.  I am assuming this will be your root directory (`http://yoursite.com`).

After that, copy your index.php and .htaccess from the existing WordPress directory (`http://yoursite.com/blog`) into your root directory.  Make sure you copy these, as opposed to moving them.

Open the new index.php (the one in your root directory) in an editor and change `require('./wp-blog-header.php');` to `require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php');`

You will still login with the old URL, `http://yoursite.com/blog/wp-admin/` but your site should now be available at `http://yoursite.com`.

I hope this helps!  If you need more information, see the link that John Watson supplied: [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install).